# How to automate process of visiting some URLs/ perform search on a specific site?

Tags: google-chrome, batch, automation, google-search

I have to make around `9992` email address searches on various breached/compromised email reporting site such as `http://haveibeenpwned.com`. I would very much like to automate this process.

My solution was to capture the POST request for e.g. `http://haveibeenpwned.com/search/email=email@address.com` and replace the variable with my 9992 email address in excel with formula `="http://haveibeenpwned.com/search/email="[9992 emails]`.

Now I have 9992 URLs to visit, for this I have download a chrome extension to automate visiting of 9992 URLs but all my handwork went to drain as the website will block this many requests in short period of time obviously. So I guess I would have to delay my searches.

I guess this could be done with Batch script as it provides delay for execution of next instruction (in this case this would be my next URL or email search). Could someone please help me with the code? Any other workaround to accomplish what I am looking for would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Surely these sites have a “premium” service that would allow you to just upload a CSV file. haveibeenpwned specifically allows to search by domain, assuming all your email addresses are part of one or more domains. And if that is sufficient they have an API to use. You’re approaching the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: Are you trying to see if your email addresses have been coopted by spammers, or if accounts associated with these addresses are associated with hacked accounts? Are these email addresses from a domain you manage?

Answer (score 2):

[AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) is the answer to your problem.

With it you can create a script to automate your mouse and keyboard movements.

You can have all of your URLs on a spreadsheet, and have AutoHotKey copy/paste the URLs into the address bar for you. You can even program it to do an 'image search' between every URL and perform a further action based on the results it finds.

So if the web result says 'You Have Been Pwned!' you can have AutoHotKey detect that image on the screen (using the image_search function), go back to your spreadsheet, highlight the cell red, and then move onto the next URL. A piece of software that will prove itself very powerful for your purposes. You just need to do some minor research to understand the basic commands required to make the script work.

So the workflow would be the following:

1. Copy URL from spreadsheet
2. Paste URL into google chrome address bar
3. Run image search on resulting webpage
4. -If image 'You have been pwned!' is detected mark cell red on spreadsheet and move onto next URL

   -If image 'You haven't been pwned' is detected - move onto next URL

Every single command in your autohotkey script can have as much delay as you want using the 'Sleep' command between lines. So 'Sleep, 1000' would instruct the script to not do anything for 1 second before moving onto the next command in the script.

Comment: Sounds like melody to my problem. I will research on it own my own but if you're willing, **Can I interact with the browser or perform other activities while AutoHotKey in progress?** The response would not be an image but an HTML response **Would it able to capture HTML response page itself?** Thank you for your targeted response.

Comment: It becomes a lot more complicated when you start asking autohotkey to get data from HTML sources. It's entirely possible but your scripting will become more advanced if choose to go down this route. You can keep it simple by asking it to detect the image 'Oh No - Pwned!' and then have it flag your cells. This will allow you to get a final list of breached addresses to focus on later. But if you want it to capture which sites it's been pwned on like spambot etc then you'll likely need to confer with the pro's on the AHK forum who have evidently helped others with similar goals.